# Would it be bad to follow up with a phone call / email after applying to a job that's posted on LinkedIn?

Tags: job-search, linkedin

Would it be bad to follow up by phone or email, after applying to a job that's posted on LinkedIn?

I'm wondering if such follow-up could be perceived positively, namely that I am proactive and care about this job enough to follow up.

Comment: `Would it be bad to follow up by phone or email, after applying to a job that's posted on LinkedIn?` - Why would it be bad? They posted the job. They're obviously looking to hire someone. Are you interested in the job? If so, then reach out to the company and let them know.

Comment: @joeqwerty for some reason, probably just paranoia, I worry about pestering them / violating some social norm, if they don't reach out first, regarding my submitted application and resume ... 

Comment: Well, don't pester them, but I see nothing wrong or inappropriate about reaching out to them to let them know of your interest in the position.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Always*** follow up.  It shows you are interested and not just blasting out your resume.

An appropriate time is 1 week.

Also, in the future, when you apply, include in the cover letter (if you can send one) the fact that you will be following up.

> Dear sir or madam,
>
> [Body of cover letter]
>
> Thank you for your time, I look forward to speaking with you about this opportunity, as a follow up, I will reach out to you next Wednesday, with an [emal/phone call/etc]
>
> Kindest regards,
>
> user100782

Comment: The "Always" part of "Always follow up" should be bold, italics, underlined, and all caps.  ALWAYS follow up.

Comment: @StanleyJointerII and Richard: interesting, thanks so much.  I was worried I'd come off pushy and / or annoying.  I'll work on the follow-up.  For now, I will indulge in some Taylor ham, egg and cheese on a roll 

Comment: @user100782 OMG did you just used a colored emoji on a SE comment? How :D?

Comment: @DarkCygnus it's a secret - you'll have to ask Shog9 or Tim Post for access to this secret functionality that I'm not at liberty to share.  

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely follow up. It shows that you are motivated and not applying "just to apply".

Just a short email or phone to check on the status of your application or to confirm the receipt goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

In college, my roommate needed a job. I got him to apply at the retail place I worked. About a week later, I made him go with me when i went to work, and told him to ask the boss if he got the application. Took 30 seconds; boss said yes, roommate thanked him and left. My roommate was not excited about the job as it was entry-level, and didn't think it was worth his time to go in person to ask a silly question. However, he needed the money and had trouble getting callbacks at the other places he'd applied.

The next week, I again made him go into work with me and inquire about decision progress. Later that shift, my boss pulled me aside and said "that buddy of yours, whose really *dedicated* and *ambitious*, I think we're going to hire him".

In truth, my roommate was neither of those things, but with an extra 90 seconds of face time over a couple occasions, he sure had the boss thinking that; he got the job, and even started at a slightly higher rate than most new-hires.

Bottom line: follow up twice before giving up or moving on, no matter what the job or how you applied.

Comment: Yeah, after a couple hundred job apps leading to nowhere, I will now implement follow-up phone calls / in-person greetings (for retail gigs) - thanks so much 